# Rand() returns negative numbers when min and max are positive

Tags: c++

I am using rand() to create random numbers. When I run my code:

```
int lowest=10000, highest=90000000000;
int range=(highest-lowest)+1;
for (int index=1; index<2; index++){
c = lowest+int(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));
```

C returns as both positive and negative numbers. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Whats the point of making a for loop that will only iterate once?

Comment: Your `highest` value (90 billion) is already larger than 2^32.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `range * rand()` overflowed and wrapped around.

This approach can't be "fixed", because you would just get `RAND_MAX` of the `range` possible values, leaving big holes that would never be chosen.  (Or, if `(INT_MAX - INT_MIN + 1) / (RAND_MAX + 1)` is smaller than `RAND_MAX`, that's how many distinct results you can get)

Use the new C++11 random number generators.

If you can't use C++11, then use bitshifting and OR operators to combine multiple `rand()` results into a single number.  If you got a number outside your range, just try again.  Any method of mapping one range onto another will break most of the nice properties of the pseudo-random number, like uniform distribution.

Comment: actually it's already the `highest` and `range` that might be negative. If you count the zeros, he got a 9e10 there and even unsigned int would only go up to around 4.3e9 given 32bit ints.